# Access nested components using Enzyme mount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm testing connected components using Enzyme.

I use a reusable `Root` component where I initialize redux store, middleware, and `redux-persist`. It looks like this (simplified):

```js
// Root.jsx
const Root = () => {
    // some logic.
    return <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
               <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
           </PersistGate>;

}
```

Then, I write my tests like this:

```js
describe("Unit Test Login", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = mount(
            <Root>
                <MemoryRouter>
                    <ConnectedAuth {...props} type="login" />
                </MemoryRouter>
            </Root>,
        )
    });

    it("renders email & password fields", () => {
        console.log(wrapper.debug());
        expect(wrapper.find(Input).length).toBe(2);
    });
});
```

**Problem**

Tests are failing and I'm unable to find elements deeply nested inside the `<Root />`. For example, finding a simple `Input` is failing.

Console.loging `wrapper.debug()` is returning the following:

```sh
<Root>
      <PersistGate loading={{...}} persistor={{...}} />
</Root>
```

How can I get deeper through the nested components tree and enable the tests to "find" the elements?

**What I've tried**

- .dive() doesn't work with `mount`
- Adding `wrapper.update()` inside each test seems to solve this problem but this isn't elegant and `wrapper.update()` inside `beforeEach()` doesn't work.

Comment: by a chance are there be operations in `PersistGate` and conditional rendering of _its_ `props.children`?

Comment: No, the children are being passed directly to the Provider without conditional rendering

Comment: Have you tried enzyme's `children()`?

Comment: Yes. `wrapper.find()` still doesn't find the nodes...